# Why DSolve cannot Find a General Solution for this ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

**The Problem Given a mass m=1 moves in potential V(x)=|x|^3;
and x(0)=1,x'(0)=0;**

So I set up

```
eq1 = Derivative[2][x][t] + 3 RealAbs[x[t]] x[t] == 0;
eq2 = x[0] == 1;
eq3 = Derivative[1][x][0] == 0;
condls = {eq1, eq2, eq3};
DSolve[condls, x[t], t]
```

It returns "DSolve::bvimp: General solution contains implicit solutions. In the boundary value problem, these solutions will be ignored, so some of the solutions will be lost."

I also tried to use alternative method like below

```
n = 3;
energy = 1/2 x'[t]^2 + RealAbs[x[t]]^n;
xSolution[t_]=x[t]/.Simplify@First[DSolve[energy==1^n&&x[0]==1&&x'[0]==0,x[t],t]]]
```

Also Would not return a solution.

I wonder what my mistake is.

Comment: You should try to find the general solution `DSolve[eq1, x, t]` and see if it's clear how to solve `C[1]` and `C[2]` for an initial condition. (That's what the message suggests to me.)

Comment: yes I tried and It returned a piecewise function with Hypergeometric2F1. I used NDSolve to obtain a plot and It looks like a  Cos function. I changed the Power of |X| to 2 and it has a real solution at x(t) =Cos[Sqrt[2] t]. I would imagine there is a solution exist as such form.

Answer (score 1):

`DSolve` does not solve the IVP, but it can solve the general equation.  We can then get an implicit solution. The solution has an extraneous branch.  I think I can probably get rid of it, but I'm out of time for the moment.

```
eq1 = Derivative[2][x][t] + 3 RealAbs[x[t]] x[t] == 0;
eq2 = x[0] == 1;
eq3 = Derivative[1][x][0] == 0;
condls = {eq1, eq2, eq3};
dsol = DSolve[eq1, x, t];
{xside, tside} = 
  Replace[dsol, 
   Verbatim[Solve][xs_ == ts_, _] :> {Simplify[xs /. x[t] -> x], ts}];
Reduce[Last@xside \[Element] Reals && C[1] > 0, x, Reals];
xmax = Simplify[MaxValue[{x, %}, x], %];
const = Solve[
   Simplify[{x0 == xmax, xside == tside /. {x -> x0, t -> t0}}, 
    x0 > 0 && C[1] > 0], {C[1], C[2]}];
(* solution for x[t0] == x0, x'[t0] == 0 *)
icsol = 
 Block[{Solve}, MapAt[Simplify, dsol /. First@const, {1, 1}]]
```

> Solve::incnst: Inconsistent or redundant transcendental equation. After reduction, the bad equation is 1-InverseFunction[Hypergeometric2F1,4,4][1/3,1/2,4/3,Hypergeometric2F1[1/3,1/2,4/3,(2 x0^3)/Subscript[[ConstantC], 1]]] == 0.
>
> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
>
> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
iceqn = Replace[
  Quiet@dsol,
  Verbatim[Solve][iceq_, ___] :> (
    iceq /. {
       x[t] -> x,
       t -> 
        Mod[t + C[2], 
          2 FullSimplify[Sqrt@Last@xside /. x -> xmax], -FullSimplify[
            Sqrt@Last@xside /. x -> xmax]] - C[2]
       } /. First@const)
  ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ContourPlot[
 iceqn /. {
    t0 -> 0,
    x0 -> 1
    } // Evaluate,
 {t, -3, 3}, {x, -2, 2}, FrameLabel -> {t, x}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> {25, 13}
 ]
```

> [image]

```
StreamPlot[{v[t], -3 RealAbs[x[t]] x[t]},
 {x[t], -1, 1}, {v[t], -1, 1},
 FrameLabel -> {x, v}]
```

> [image]